# Objectmapper get array of one item within JSON

Tags: arrays, json, swift, realm, objectmapper

So I have the following JSON, which I am using together with ObjectMapper and Realm.

```
{
  "result": [
    {
      "id": 20,
      "types": [
        "now"
      ],
      "url": "/nl/whereto/ezrhgerigerg",
      "categories": [
        {
          "id": 39,
          "name": "Food "
        },
        {
          "id": 21,
          "name": "Varia"
        }
      ]
    },
```

My problem is getting the data from "types", which for some items in the array says "now" or "later", and is empty for other items (hence, no types item is given).

I tried to do the following in my mapping:

```
class Publication: Object, Mappable {
    dynamic var id:Int = 0
    var typez  = List<getType>()
    dynamic var url:String?

    required convenience init?(_ map: Map) {
        self.init()
    }

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        id <- map["id"]
        typez <- map["types"]
        url <- map["url"]
    }
}

class getType: Object, Mappable {
    dynamic var text: String = ""


    required convenience init?(_ map: Map) {
        self.init()
    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        text <- map[""]
    }
}
```

When I check the Realm database, you can see that typez, an array of [getType] was made, but it's empty for all items (even the ones where types is "now"). The other two items (id and url) are filled in in the database.

What am I doing wrong that it won't save to the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because Realm cannot detect assigning `List` properties since `List` property is not Objective-C type. So `List` properties should be declared as `let`, and should not be `nil`. You should use `append`/remove...`/`insert...`method to modifying the`List`.

So your code

```
typez <- map["types"]
```

doesn't work, since you assign values to the `typez` property directly.

The workaround is like the following:

```
func mapping(map: Map) {
    ...
    var typez: [String]? = nil
    typez <- map["types"]

    typez?.forEach { t in
        let obj = getType()
        obj.text = t
        self.typez.append(obj)
    }
    ...
```

First, store the mapped value to the local variable (it is string array). Then convert the string array to objects. Then append the objects to the `List` property.

Comment: small question: when I do it this way, and update the data from the database (checking backend for changes), it just keeps stacking this information upon the previous. (only for this array in my db). Is there any way to stop this from happening?

Comment: I think it doesn't occur because `mapping` function is only called initializing. But if it would occur, the solution is clear `typez` before loop. To clear the `List` object, call `removeAll()`.

Comment: This deletes the objects from my List, but not from the Database. I want to delete the items within the list first (and the database) before filling it up again with updated data.

Comment: could you maybe add a short template on how to do it? I now did `typez.removeAll()` before the `typez?.forEach`, but this just deletes the List itself for that Object, but they are still in the database.