# Filtering Realm objects with Swift

Tags: swift, nspredicate, realm

I always get the following error when trying to filter my Realm database using `NSPredicate`:

> Property 'text' is not a link in object of type 'getType'

I want to filter my Realm database to show only the items that have some specific text in them. This is what I've tried:

```
let realm = try! Realm()
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "typez.text.filter = 'special'")
let filterThis = realm.objects(Publication).filter(predicate)
print(filterThis)
```

The relevant portion of my model classes is:

```
class Publication: Object, Mappable {
    dynamic var id: Int = 0
    var typez = List<getType>()
    dynamic var url: String?
}

class getType: Object, Mappable {
    dynamic var text: String = ""
}
```

Comment: What's your `Publication` object implementation?

Comment: can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36835805/objectmapper-get-array-of-one-item-within-json

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't usually use NSPredicate's directly, instead I do an inline predicate closure within the filter paramter.

```
let realm = try! Realm()
                     //Array of publications             
    let realmObjects = realm.objects(Publication)
    //any publication where .text property == special will be filtered. and filter out empty array
    let filterThis = realmObjects.filter({ $0.getType.filter({ $0.text == "special" } != [] ) })
    print(filterThis)
```

Comment: I recommend this [article](https://www.weheartswift.com/higher-order-functions-map-filter-reduce-and-more/) to learn more cool tricks with the new swift array methods including how to use the `$0.property` closure syntax with filter/map/reduce

Comment: Gives me the following error: `Cannot invoke 'filter' with an argument list of type '((_) -> _)'`. When i make the class Equatable, it says it's a redundant conformance.

Comment: You shouldn't need to use equateable if your `.text` property is a String because strings are equatable. Try casting. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Tried it, got back that the type of expression is ambigious without more context, and an error saying `Value of type 'Publication' has no member 'text'`, which is correct indeed, because it can be found under the [getType] array, not the publication object itself.

Comment: So this is a 2 dimensional Array?

Comment: So the object (named Publication) has fields like ID (Int), URL(string) and typez(which is an array of getType). So when you access Publication.text, it doesn't exist, because it is under the [getType] field. If you want to see the structure of the Realm db, check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36835805/objectmapper-get-array-of-one-item-within-json

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110171/discussion-between-nsgangster-and-soundshock).

Comment: Please be aware that there are a number of disadvantages to filtering based on a closure like this answer demonstrates: performance and memory overhead will be worse, the resulting collection will not automatically update when the Realm changes, and you don't have access to functionality like notifications.

Comment: Filtering with closure is significantly slower than with NSPredicate, like hundred times of time consumption.

Answer (score 11):

You mentioned that the relevant portions of you model classes look like so:

```
class Publication: Object, Mappable {
    dynamic var id: Int = 0
    var typez = List<getType>()
    dynamic var url: String?
}

class getType: Object, Mappable {
    dynamic var text: String = ""
}
```

If I understand you correctly, you want to find `Publication` instances that have an entry in their `typez` list with `text` equal to `special`. You can express that as:

```
let realm = try! Realm()
let result = realm.objects(Publication).filter("ANY typez.text = 'special'")
print(result)
```

Comment: Tried that before, but got the error `Key paths that include an array property must use aggregate operations'`

Comment: My mistake. You need to include a modifier like `ANY` to specify how many elements in the `List` must match for the containing object to be considered a match. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I was not liking the accepted answer here because it doesn't actually answer the question... but then it helped me more than I realized. I will now be using closures instead of NSPredicates whenever possible. The actual answer to this question should be a slightly modified version of @NSGangster's answer:

```
let realm = try! Realm()
    //Array of publications             
    let realmObjects = realm.objects(Publication)
    //any publication where .text property == special will be filtered. and filter out empty array
    let filterThis = realmObjects.filter({ $0.typez.filter({ $0.text == "special" } != [] ) })
    print(filterThis)
```

.. or something close to that.

But what I was looking for was a bit different. I needed a way to filter on exact words of a multi-word string, and using an NSPredicate with "CONTAINS" would match any containing substring, e.g. a search for "red" would match "fred". Realm doesn't support "LIKE" or regex yet, so using a closure was the only thing I could get to work:

```
//I was going for a "related terms" result for a dictionary app
let theResults = terms.filter(
    {
        //Looking for other terms in my collection that contained the
        //title of the current term in their definition or more_info strings
        $0.definition.components(separatedBy: " ").contains(term.title) ||
        $0.more_info.components(separatedBy: " ").contains(term.title)
    }
)
```

With as much of the day as I spent searching, hopefully this helps someone else with a similar issue.

Comment: Realm supports `LIKE` as of early v2.1.2. Please also be aware that there are a number of disadvantages to filtering based on a closure like you demonstrate: performance and memory overhead will be worse, the resulting collection will not automatically update when the Realm changes, and you don't have access to functionality like notifications.