# How to create a pre bundled realm file and upload data to it?

Tags: ios, swift, database, realm

I am new to Realm and I want to ship a pre bundled Realm file my app, however the [realm documentation](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#bundling-a-realm-with-an-app) is unclear to me on how to actually create a .realm file and also upload the desired pre bundled data to it.  I have not been able to find any solution via SO, Google, or Youtube. Step-by-step instructions would be very helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We're still looking at ways to officially make generating pre-populated Realms more easy. It's definitely a desired feature for the Realm Browser, but due to the way that Realm files require a migration when changing the schema, it's somewhat tricky to incorporate into a UI. It's definitely something we want to improve down the line.

At the moment, the Browser has [a converter in it](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa-converter) that can perform minimal data import like CSV files.

The Realm documentation is saying that the easiest way for you to produce a pre-populated Realm specific for your apps needs is to build a separate macOS app whose sole role is to generate the Realm file, pre-populate the data and then expose the resulting Realm file so you can copy it to your app.

The operation to do this is just like any normal Realm interaction (`try! Realm()` is what causes the file to actually be initially created), except you manually interact with the Realm file on disk upon completion.

I'm working on an app for an iOS conference, and the schedule data for the event is going to be stored in a Realm that is pre-bundled with the app when it ships.

Since I thought creating an extra macOS app would be overkill for an iOS app, I instead used iOS unit tests that would generate the pre-bundled Realm from scratch every time it was executed.

```
class Tests: XCTestCase {
    func testGenerateNewDefaultRealm() {
        let sources = [conferences, sponsors, conferenceDays] as [Any]
        XCTAssert(generateDefaultRealm(named: "MyConferenceRealm.realm", sources: sources))
    }
}

extension Tests {
    public func generateDefaultRealm(named name: String, sources: [Any]) -> Bool {
        // Create and configure the Realm file we'll be writing to
        let realm = generateRealm(named: name)

        // Open a Realm write transaction
        realm.beginWrite()

        // Loop through each source and add it to Realm
        for source in sources {
            if let objectArray = source as? [Object] {
                for object in objectArray {
                    realm.add(object)
                }
            }
            else if let objectDictionary = source as? [String : Object] {
                for (_, object) in objectDictionary {
                    realm.add(object)
                }
            }
        }

        // Commit the write transaction
        do {
            try realm.commitWrite()
        }
        catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return false
        }

        // Print the file location of the generated Realm
        print("=====================================================================")
        print(" ")
        print("Successfully generated at")
        print(realm.configuration.fileURL!.path)
        print(" ")
        print("=====================================================================")

        return true
    }

    public func generateRealm(named name: String) -> Realm {
        let exportPath = NSTemporaryDirectory()
        let realmPath = exportPath.appending(name)

        // Delete previous Realm file
        if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: realmPath) {
            try! FileManager.default.removeItem(atPath: realmPath)
        }

        // Create new Realm file at path
        let objectTypes: [Object.Type] = [Conference.self, ConferenceDay.self, SessionBlock.self, Event.self, Presentation.self,
                                          Session.self, Location.self, Speaker.self, Sponsor.self, Venue.self]
        let configuration = Realm.Configuration(fileURL: URL(string: realmPath), objectTypes: objectTypes)
        let realm = try! Realm(configuration: configuration)
        return realm
    }
}
```

Running this unit test will generate a new Realm file in the `NSTemporaryDirectory()` directory of the Mac, and then feed in a set of `Array` and `Dictionary` objects of un-persisted Realm `Object` instances that are created each time the test is run. The location of the final Realm is then printed in the console so I can grab it and move it to the app bundle.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I have a Parse database that I query multiple Collections, and I currently have a method that runs all the queries at once (when the user logs in) is it possible to put data from different Collections in the same .realm file? If so how would I go about extracting the data from my method and saving it to the file? Also what does XCTAssert refer to? @TiM

Comment: No worries! If this answers your question, please remember to accept it. :) Yep! It should be possible. I'm guessing Parse just calls a local method in your app when the query completes. At that point you'd just copy the data to Realm via a write transaction as normal. If you're going to be writing to a pre-bundled Realm, you'll have to copy it to a section in your app where you're allowed to write data. Most likely the Documents directory.

Comment: I was able to create a bundled realm file however it is huge (68 GB) and I want to compress it in order to add it to my project.  What is the best way to go about this? In the docs it says to use `Realm().writeCopy.(toFile: _ ,encryptionKey:)` but my file path is extremely long and I get an error saying I can't put a string for my path.  Some advice would be much appreciated. @TiM

Comment: Also my realm file is already in the Documents folder, however when trying to read from it I get an error back **fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value** so it doesn't seem like I'm accessing the file.  How can I make sure I'm accessing the file? @TiM

Comment: Uhh, that's pretty big! What are you putting in there? You can use the Realm Browser to export a compacted copy of that Realm that you should be able to then copy to your app's bundle. Umm, I can't help with the second point sorry; that's a really generic Swift error.

Comment: FYI the compression came up huge. I was able to reduce the file size from 68 GB to 1.3 MB. @TiM

Comment: I now have copied it in my project directory, so in order to read/write from/to it I need to copy it into my Documents folder correct? I'm following this [tutorial](https://videos.raywenderlich.com/courses/intermediate-realm-on-ios/lessons/2) to do so.

Comment: Ah! Good to hear! 1.3MB is a bit more manageable. :) If you only need to read from it, you can leave it in your app bundle. But yes, if you want to write to it, you'll need to move it to a section in your app that has write access. `Documents` is good if you're not exposing it in iTunes, `Application Support` is good otherwise. :)

Comment: I'm trying to access one element out of the `List` array with this method `private func bookPredicate(_ book:String) -> NSPredicate {
        
        return NSPredicate(format: "bookTitle.book = %@", book)
    }` but I get the following error **'Invalid predicate', reason: 'Key paths that include an array property must use aggregate operations'** what is the best way to handle this? @TiM

Comment: In regards to your [response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36843480/filtering-realm-objects-with-swift) I have a similar situation.  `var results = realm.objects(CollegeData.self)`  `if let predicate = majorsPredicate(filter.major) {
            results = results.filter("ANY collegeMajors.major = '%@'", predicate)
        }` **predicate** holds a value but when I pass it to **results** , **results** is empty printing this in the console `Results<CollegeData> (

)`. Any idea why this is and how to fix it? @bdash