# Realm and Objectmapper: Array of one item keeps stacking in my Realm database for every request

Tags: json, swift, realm, objectmapper, realm-list

This is a follow-up on one of my [previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36835805/objectmapper-get-array-of-one-item-within-json/36836839?noredirect=1#comment61455736_36836839) here. I needed to map an array `types` in my Realm database, which consists of only 1 word (sometimes two), with the help of ObjectMapper.

This is the JSON:

```
{
  "result": [
    {
      "id": 20,
      "types": [
        "now"
      ],
      "url": "/nl/whereto/ezrhgerigerg"
    },
```

I got the following work-around, which worked partly:

```
func mapping(map: Map) {
...
var typez: [String]? = nil
typez <- map["types"]

typez?.forEach { t in
    let obj = getType()
    obj.text = t
    self.typez.append(obj)
}
```

And my Class of `getType()` which is an  object:

```
class getType: Object, Mappable {
    dynamic var text: String?

    required convenience init?(_ map: Map) {
        self.init()
    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        text <- map[""]
    }
}
```

The issue I'm having, is that every time I do a call to the backend, the database doesn't update the data in types (or deletes them, and grabs the new ones), it just keeps piling it up! This is making my getType database 280+ rows after some calls, while it is only present in 10 objects.

After x number of backend calls, this will cause a serious issue. Does anyone know what I should do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you probably updated the `Publication` object using the primary key. Unfortunately, the `getType` object doesn't have a primary key. It cannot be updated automatically with the primary key.

So you can delete `typez` property manually if the publication object already exists. Like the following:

```
let publication = Mapper<Publication>().map(json)
// ...
try! realm.write {
    // Check whether the Publication　object already exists
    let key = ... // Primary key value (e.g. 20)
    if let publication = realm.objectForPrimaryKey(Publication.self, key: key) {
        // If it already exists, delete `typez` objects
        realm.delete(publication.typez)
    }

    realm.add(publication, update: true)
}
```

Comment: returns the following error: uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Invalid value 'id' for primary key'

Comment: @SoundShock Sorry, it's my fault. The `key` parameter is wrong. A primary key value should be passed to the `key` parameter, like `20`. I edited my answer.